# Is there a way to compare unordered Lists with Equatable package in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, list, dart, comparison, equatable

I createad a class Question that extends equatable: it has a property named "answers" which is a List of String of dimension 4. I would like to compare 2 questions that have the same answers, whose items are unordered. Any ideas on how to do it? Overriding the props with [answers] is not enough...
Thanks!
Here is the question model:

```
@immutable

/// Question class to model the api response: it will be
/// used in the Presentation layer
class Question extends Equatable {
  final String question;
  final String correctAnswer;
  final List<dynamic>? answers;

  const Question({
    required this.question,
    required this.correctAnswer,
    this.answers,
  });

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [
        question,
        correctAnswer,
        answers,
      ];
```

then i create a QuestionModelResponse that extends the Question class (that represents the data that i want to visualize) that has a method **toEntity()** to convert it into a question:

```
@immutable
class QuestionResponseModel extends Question {
  final List<dynamic> incorrectAnswers;

  const QuestionResponseModel({
    required correctAnswer,
    required question,
    required this.incorrectAnswers,
  }) : super(
          correctAnswer: correctAnswer,
          question: question,
        );

  factory QuestionResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return QuestionResponseModel(
      question: map['question'] ?? '',
      correctAnswer: map['correct_answer'] ?? '',
      incorrectAnswers: map['incorrect_answers'] ?? [],
    );
  }

  Question toEntity() {
    return Question(
        question: question,
        correctAnswer: correctAnswer,
        answers: incorrectAnswers
          ..add(correctAnswer)
          ..shuffle());
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [
        question,
        correctAnswer,
        incorrectAnswers,
      ];
}
```

and this is a sample of the json response:

```
{
    "response_code": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "category": "Entertainment: Books",
            "type": "multiple",
            "difficulty": "medium",
            "question": "What is the fourth book of the Old Testament?",
            "correct_answer": "Numbers",
            "incorrect_answers": [
                "Genesis",
                "Exodus",
                "Leviticus"
            ]
        },
}
```

Comment: add sample code

Comment: ... and sample data.

Comment: If order doesn't matter, then use `Set`s instead of `List`s.  Or just sort the `List`s before comparing them.

Comment: @jamesdlin Well, that would take some work to use **SET** because the json returns a **LIST**. To sort the list is not a bad idea, but i would like to use something of the equatable package if there is.

Comment: What the JSON returns does not dictate how you store that data in your object model.

Comment: @jamesdlin Ok i see, so basically i would need to convert the list received from json to a set during the mapping, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Dart `Set` are equal if the values are same even the objects are in different order.

In your case, you can convert `List` into a `Set` with `toSet()` method while comparing two different lists.

`listA.toSet() == listB.toSet()`

Comment: Yes, finally i modified the values of my get props method as follow: @override
  List<Object?> get props => [
        question,
        correctAnswer,
        answers?.toSet(),
      ];

Comment: @Andi be aware there could be a significant cost do do this in the compare as toSet is called every time an element is compared. It may be better to modify the field to be a set if that is actually what it is.